# What time-series model to use for mostly linear, but limited values?

Tags: time-series, bounds

I'm interested in fitting a model to several types of time series that all behave similarly:

- Depth of a work queue
- Disk space available
- Idle CPU time available

None of these values can go below zero, but otherwise their behavior is relatively independent of value. (e.g. disk space is as likely to move from 25% to 26% as it is from 75% to 76%.) Some of these, like disk space and idle CPU time, also have upper limits that they cannot pass - a disk cannot be more than 100% full.

As long as these values stay away from their limits, I suspect traditional time series models like ARIMA or Holt-Winters would model them fairly well, but I'd like to encode the behavior at the limits.

What models can encode these behaviors?

Comment: If behavior doesn't change even very close to the limit, you might treat it as truncated at the limit. I don't have any experience with doing this with time series though.

Comment: If they are bound by 0 and 1, you might try a logit transformation before you model. This transformation ensures that when you transform back, you are always between 0 and 1.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit

Comment: A logit transform does keep it between zero and one, but the logit asymptotically approaches zero or one, meaning any model using the logit transform would shy away from hitting 0 or 1. My data doesn't behave like that - when a queue gets empty, it gets empty.